# Libreoffice 5.1.6.2 "The dictionary is already full."

Tags: libreoffice

I've previously used a medical dictionary file for Word that has 98119 terms in it.  I created the file using the Libreoffice "Tool > Spelling and Grammar > Options > New" dialogue.

Then I exited Libreoffice and navigated to "~/.config/libreoffice/4/user/wordbook" where I populated the new .dic file with the wordlist.

All words in that list still appear as misspelled despite the dictionary being enabled.  Trying to add words to that dictionary via "right click > Add to Dictionary" returns a dialogue with the message "The dictionary is already full."

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or that maybe Libreoffice can't handle dictionaries of this size.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Upgraded to 5.3.4.2 and the issue persists.